# How to merge array inside object in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, amcharts

I have decoded json like this:

```
[
    {
        "ID": "120",
        "NAME": "KRETEK",
        "children": [
            {
                "IDS": "01107",
                "VALUE": "6761114",
                "NAME": "GUD"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "ID": "120",
        "NAME": "KRETEK",
        "children": [
            {
                "IDS": "01108",
                "VALUE": "57904",
                "NAME": "POER"
            }
        ]
    },

]
```

is it possible to transform it into this?

```
[
    {
        "ID": "120",
        "NAME": "KRETEK",
        "children": [
            {
                "IDS": "01107",
                "VALUE": "6761114",
                "NAME": "GUD"
            },
            {
                "IDS": "01108",
                "VALUE": "57904",
                "NAME": "POER"
            }
        ]
    },
   
]
```

the data above was intended for amchart (https://www.amcharts.com/demos/collapsible-force-directed-tree/), thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Is it possible? Yes. Share some code for what you've attempted so far and what's not working, and then others will be able to provide specific help

Comment: Thank @KevinHooke for the reminder, I'm new in Javascript and here in stackoverflow. in I've tried using Flat() and Object.Assign, but i think, the information about it will make the post confusing, I will take note of code for I've attempted so far in my future post, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think u can use array reduce and array find

```js
const data = [
    {
        "ID": "120",
        "NAME": "KRETEK",
        "children": [
            {
                "IDS": "01107",
                "VALUE": "6761114",
                "NAME": "GUD"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "ID": "120",
        "NAME": "KRETEK",
        "children": [
            {
                "IDS": "01108",
                "VALUE": "57904",
                "NAME": "POER"
            }
        ]
    },

]

const mergeArray = (originalArr) => {
  return originalArr.reduce((previous, obj) => {
      const isSameID = previous.find(item => item.ID === obj.ID)
      if (isSameID) {
        isSameID.children.push(...obj.children)
      } else {
        previous.push(obj);
      }
      return previous;
  }, [])
}

console.log(mergeArray(data))
```

Comment: Thank @TimoDevs, the code works well for me. Thank You so much

Comment: glad to help ^^